# How to receive binary file as response and render file using javascript?

Tags: javascript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9u18.png)We have a service that interacts with box.com and returns a file in binary format.

I am trying to hit that service from java-script to get binary file and render/dowload as actual file using below code but no response is being received (I have verified that service is returning the response).
Console logs are blank.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<h1>File Download</h1>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Download</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

```js
function loadDoc() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', URL, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic xxcxcsdfdfdferererer=");
    //xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", true);
    xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify({projects: [{id: "xxxxxx", fileId: "1234456566"}]}));
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status === 200) {
            var filename = "";
            var disposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
            if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
                var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
                var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);  
                if (matches != null && matches[1]) filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
            }
            var type = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
            var blob = typeof File === 'function' ? new File([this.response], filename, { type: type }) : new Blob([this.response], { type: type });
            if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {
                // IE workaround for "HTML7007: One or more blob URLs were revoked by closing the blob for which they were created. These URLs will no longer resolve as the data backing the URL has been freed."
                window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
            } else {
                var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                if (filename) {
                    // use HTML5 a[download] attribute to specify filename
                    var a = document.createElement("a");
                    // safari doesn't support this yet
                    if (typeof a.download === 'undefined') {
                        window.location = downloadUrl;
                    } else {
                        a.href = downloadUrl;
                        a.download = filename;
                        document.body.appendChild(a);
                        a.click();
                    }
                } else {
                    window.location = downloadUrl;
                }
                setTimeout(function () { URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl); }, 100); // cleanup
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I see by `.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", true` you think you can bypass CORS - no, the server sends the Access-Control-**ALLOW**-Origin - you can't tell the server to give you response it doesn't want to give you  - CORS is a mechanism to protect site owners from other site owners "borrowing" their resources. If it were as simple as saying "oh, you will let me have that resource", then CORS would be pointless - see [CORS documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) to learn about CORS

Comment: I agree, It's pointless but the actual issue still persists with or without that.

Comment: Yes, the problem does persist because CORS can't be bypassed like that. CORS protects websites resources from being "borrowed" by other websites - perhaps "box.com" has an API you can use that ALLOWS you to "borrow" their resources. Or, failing that, you'll need to "proxy" your requests to "box.com" via your own server, thereby removing the CORS issue altogether

Comment: CORS issue was taken care of. We have a middleware system which fetches file from box.com. So for us, middleware is the server to be contacted and we have tested this with rest client "Postman tool" successfully. But with java-script (which is running from secured server), couldn't succeed. Attached is what I am seeing in console after a minute or two since request is made.

Comment: `CORS issue was taken care of.` then why are you sending CORS response headers in the request? `tested this with rest client "Postman tool"` Postman isn't subject to CORS anyway. `Attached is what I am seeing in console after a minute or two` a timeout issue perhaps? I take it `URL` in `xhr.open('POST', URL, true);` is **same origin** then

Comment: Yes, please ignore CORS response header in the request. I happened to copy-paste unrefined version but actual core logic is same. I tried to fetch very small file (just few KBs) to validate the time-out factor, but no luck. I apologize for making it not clear, please let me know if there is any way to handle (confirm) timeout issue.

Comment: is `this.readyState == 4 && this.status === 200` ever true? if not, then there's nothing more I can help with

Comment: Thank you Jaromanda!, you were right about "proxy" request to remove CORS issue altogether and we did that. I have verified this again after reading your comments and found that the library files in the proxy are parsing requests and responses to JSON. But for file upload and download, it has to be single object (multi-form data) instead of JSON. Appreciate your help on this!